# XDebug with Geany?

Tags: php, xdebug, geany

Is it possible to configure PHP XDebug with Geany?

XDebug as in: http://xdebug.org/
and Geany as in: http://www.geany.org/

If it is possible, how can it be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not right now.

It has been in [Geany plugin wishlist](http://www.geany.org/Support/PluginWishlist) for some time though, so it way happen some day.

Instead, you can use xdebug plugin for Eclipse and some others, listed [here](http://xdebug.org/docs/remote).